# Php not repeating random value

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

How can I get a not repeating random value, I tried this but did not work got an error:

```
    $randomdate = mt_rand(1, 52);
    $newdate = shuffle($randomdate);
    echo $newdate;
```

And got this error:

> Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

Comment: What do you mean with "not repeating"? tried with `rand(1,52);` ?

Comment: return of mt_rand is integer not array, as the warning says

Comment: with not repeating I mean not to repeat an integer which was already randomed so to say. The random function repeats its self 10 times. For instance its randomed 4 at first but should not repeat 4 anymore on the other tries

Comment: But the error explains it all: `mt_rand` echoes only one integer. In order to shuffle something, you need an array (of possibly more elements).

Comment: Are you asking how to generate random numbers or why `shuffle` is generating an error. **Its not clear from your question and comments**

Comment: I mean that I want to create not repeating numbers and that I tried to shuffle, but that it did not work properly

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**:

```
$nums = range(1, 52);
shuffle($nums);
while (sizeof($nums)) print array_pop($nums)."\n";
```

(Thanks to XicoXperto and Kevinrob.)

**Full version:**

I understand from your question update that you mean "*I want a list of unique numbers, randomly ordered*".

For that you can use the (not particularly awesome-sauce) `shuffle()` (which you obviously know of!)

`shuffle()` only operates on arrays (thus your error message) - so we need to generate an array of integers from 1 to 52 inclusive:

```
$nums = array();                  // Declare empty array
for ($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++) {    // From 1 to 52 inclusive
   $nums[] = $i;                  //   Populate unique numbers in array
}
shuffle($nums);                   // Shuffle array randomly
```

Now we can just start popping / shifting numbers off the array:

```
while (sizeof($nums) > 0) {
   print array_shift($nums) . "\n";
}
```

---

Optimised version (kudos to Kevinrob):

```
$nums = range(1, 52);             // Declare array of numbers 1..52
shuffle($nums);                   // Shuffle array randomly
```

Performance is doubled:

```
Loop:  0.48s (10,000)
Range: 0.26s (10,000)
```

---

Another optimisation provided regarding `array_shift` vs `array_pop` - the latter is less intensive - it'll give no less "randomness" (just works off the other end of the array) - thanks to XicoXperto!

```
array_shift: 2.20s (100,000)
array_pop:   1.40s (100,000)
```

Comment: You can use `range(1, 52)` instead of your loop for ;)

Comment: prefer *array_pop* to *array_shift* every time that it's not demanded to be the first item of the list. This avoids all the re-index of all elements

Comment: Thanks XicoXperto - I'm a sucker for squeezing every last bit out in production ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use **array_rand()** to random and pick N values (in this case, 10 times as you said), and **range()** to set limits, in your case, from 1 to 52.

```
<?php

    print_r( array_rand( range( 1, 52 ), 10 ) );

?>
```

Or, if you want to **shuffle()** results, then...

```
<?php

$numbers = array_rand( range( 1, 52 ), 10 ) ;
shuffle( $numbers );
print_r( $numbers );

?>
```

Comment: Neat solution!  Also is repeatably marginally faster than mine by about 5%.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this (that I can think atm)

#### 1st way

```
$totalRandomNumbers = 4;
$randomValues = range(1, 52);
$result = array_rand($randomValues, $totalRandomNumbers);
```

variables:

- `$totalRandomNumbers` is the total of random values that you want to get
- `$results` the array variable that will contain the random values
- `$randomValues` will be a array with all the possible values (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 50, 51, 52)

logic:
- `range(1, 52)` generate the array with all values from 1 to 52
- `array_rand($randomValues, $totalRandomNumbers)` will get randomly the amount of `$totalRandomNumbers` from the `$randomValues` list

#### 2nd way *REMOVED*

> it would take loads amount of processing and that means more time, so I took it